# How to set font color of ToolTip in fluent-ui

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react, office-ui-fabric-react

Not able to set font color of ToolTipHost in fluent-ui, I tried below code but it is not working.

```
<TooltipHost content="Tooltip Content"
    calloutProps: {
      styles: {
        calloutMain: { background: 'red',color:'white' },
      },
    },
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `tooltipProps` and `styles` inside it:

```
<TooltipHost
   ...
   tooltipProps={{
     styles: {
       content: { color: '#f00' }
     }
   }}
/>
```

Full working example [Codepen](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/LYWoERY?editors=0010).